# Best practice for Bash start-up files on a Mac

Tags: macos, bash

As I understand it, the order that start-up files are read by the bash shell on a Mac are...

1. ~/.bash_profile
2. ~/.bash_login
3. ~/.profile

..and once one file in this list is found, the contents of the other is ignored.

That being said, is there a best practice for which of these files should be my one true Bash start-up file?

On one hand, if .bash_profile will take precedence over any other potential start-up file, then that should be used, because you can be sure that 100% of the time the info in that start-up file is being run.

On the other hand, if .profile is the file that exists on Mac systems by default, and .bash_profile needs to be manually created, then perhaps that should be used, and there will never be a reason to create a .bash_profile file.

Thoughts?

Comment: `.profile` doesn't exist by default.

Comment: Interesting. So if .profile doesn't exist by default, what's the case for ever using .profile over .bash_profile?

Comment: `.profile` is for all shells, `.bash_profile` is just for bash.

Comment: /etc/profile exists by default.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It depends on whether you use shells other than bash, and whether you use bash-only features in your profile.  If you use other sh-style shells (sh, ksh, zsh, etc but not csh or tcsh), don't use bash-only features and want the same setup no matter what shell you're in, you should use .profile.  If you want to use bash-only features, use .bash_profile.  If you want to use multiple shells but also use bash-only features, put the common stuff in .profile and the bash-only stuff in .bash_profile, then add `if [ -f ~/.profile ]; then . ~/.profile; fi` to .bash_profile.

If you only ever use bash, but don't rely on any bash-only features in your profile, then it doesn't really matter.

There's actually another complication: login bash shells source either .bash_profile, .bash_login, or .profile; non-login interactive bash shells (e.g. subshells) source .bashrc instead.  I tend to want the same setup in both login and non-login shells, so I put all the interesting stuff in .bashrc, and then `if [ -f ~/.bashrc ]; then . ~/.bashrc; fi` in .bash_profile.  If I also used other shells, I'd probably put most of it in .profile instead, and have .bashrc source that instead.

Comment: Great post. Regarding the last point though, .*profile is the right place for things that should only be done once, such as adding stuff to the various PATHs. Hence I don't think sourcing .*profile from .*rc is a great idea, because you would end up doing that more than once when invoking a shell from an existing session. I'd add a common .shrc (or some such name) and soure that from the shell-specific .*rc's.

Comment: @ak2 True.  I rerun my .bashrc at the drop of a hat, so it's written to avoid such problems (see [this](http://superuser.com/questions/39751/add-directory-to-path-if-its-not-already-there/39995#39995) for how I avoid redundant PATH entries), and I tend to forget about this.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case, I had a problem before where I had a lost configuration somewhere and took me a long time to find it, mainly because I was a noob.

I was looking into these user specific files these users very well determined, but the configuration was set on /etc/profile.

Just in case.